# Is it possible to adjust mouse wheel scroll distance on a WPF ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I find it is scrolling too much at a time when the mouse scroll wheel is used. I have a very short `ScrollViewer` (one line tall) that contains a few lines of items in a `WrapPanel`, and it is scrolling right to the bottom in one "tick" so that the middle line is never visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not nice solution but you could add a few panes with text - one panel each line

`ScrollViewer` class uses `IScrollInfo` interface and there are 2 methods.

```
((IScrollInfo)myPanel).LineUp();// and LineDown()
```

Add a method to `UIElement.MouseWheel` event and one rotation == one children of a panel.

...or you could use:

```
 myScrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
```

Comment: Hmm, I suppose if I could intercept the mousewheel event I could scroll the scrollviewer manually as you suggest, given that I know how tall a "line" is (which in this case I do). I'll try it out.