# UI Scrollbar Scroll Sensitivity For Mouse Wheel Scroll

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am trying to adjust the scrollbar scroll speed because it is too slow.
I only found this on the web. But I don't know how to use it.

```
UI.ScrollRect.scrollSensitivity
```

I am trying this to create a `Text` that contains some information (like what's new in unity 5.3? )

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358962/is-it-possible-to-adjust-mouse-wheel-scroll-distance-on-a-wpf-scrollviewer

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1029338/new-ui-scrollrect-sensitivity-for-mouse-wheel-and.html

Comment: he says that he increased the scroll sensivity 1 to 27. Where he have done it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what is your problem, and I hope this is the solution for it.

You were trying to set the value of `UI.ScrollRect.scrollSensitivity` without an instance of `ScrollRect` object.

To set the sensitivity you need an instance of it and set it like this:

```
public ScrollRect scroll;

void Start()
{
      scroll.scrollSensitivity = 27f;
}
```

Also you can set it directly from Inpsector:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I haven't saw it before.